# Need to open PSSession to each SQL Server to run a query

Tags: powershell

I've got to pull SUM of a column from a table on 7 SQL Servers. I've never used SQL PS before.

Seems the only way I can get it working is to open a PS Session to each server and run the query. Is that right?

I'm trying to work out how to authenticate to each one and just open the PS Session once to get the cmdlets from the first server.

I've tried just opening the first one and then running the query with the Credentials switch but that gives me a logon error.

```
[array] $SQLServers= @("SQLSERVER1","SQLSERVER2","SQLSERVER3","SQLSERVER4","SQLSERVER5","SQLSERVER6","SQLSERVER7")
#$credentials = Get-Credential
$report = @()
$username = "domain\username"
$password = Get-Content 'PathToSecureTextFile' | ConvertTo-SecureString
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
         -argumentlist $username, $password

$reportQuery = @"

SELECT SUM(COLUMNNAME) FROM TABLENAME

"@

foreach ($SQLServer in $SQLServers){

    Switch ($SQLServer){
        "SQLSERVER1" {$pod = "POD1";
                      $database = "DATABASE01"}
        "SQLSERVER2" {$pod = "POD2";
                      $database = "DATABASE02"}
        "SQLSERVER3" {$pod = "POD3";
                      $database = "DATABASE03"}
        "SQLSERVER4" {$pod = "POD4";
                      $database = "DATABASE04"}
        "PDC2SQL071" {$pod = "POD5";
                      $database = "DATABASE05"}
        "PDC2SQL072" {$pod = "POD6";
                      $database = "DATABASE06"}
        "PDC2SQL073" {$pod = "POD7";
                      $database = "DATABASE07"}

    }


    Write-Host "you are using Server" $SQLServer "with database " $database

    $newSQLPS = New-PSSession -ComputerName $SQLServer -Credential $cred
    Import-Module -Name SQLPS -PSSession $newSQLPS

    [int]$dataMigrated = [math]::Round(((Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLServer `
         -Database $Database -Query $reportQuery).Column1/1024/1024/1024),2)

    $props = [ordered]@{
        Pod = $pod
        DataMigrated = $datamigrated
    }

    Write-host "Server $SQLServer Migated $datamigrated GB" -ForegroundColor Green
    Write-Host "==========================================" -ForegroundColor Yellow

    $reportRow = New-Object psobject -Property $props
    $report += $reportRow

}

#New-Object PSObject -Property $report
$report
```

This does work and I get the results I want but I'm just thinking if I could authenticate properly then the script would run a lot quicker.

Comment: You say it works and you get a logon error too. Thats a bit confusing to me. The credential object seems like you are creating it correctly. If you could add the full error message as well, we could help better. Also, I don't think you really need a `PSSession` to run SQL Query. You can run it from your local machine as long as you have the `SQLServer` PowerShell module installed.

Comment: `Invoke-Sqlcmd` has a `-Credential` parameter you can pass the creds to, you don't need to establish a new ps session per target server

Comment: Hi Sid, Sorry I should have clarified it works importing a PS Session to every server in the loop but that seems inefficient. I was looking for a way to pass it to the command. Mathias I can't see a -credentials switch only a -username and -password but those are only used for SQL creds not domain.